# apache pass domain through mod_proxy to validate with mod_access

Tags: apache-2.2

I have an apache proxy server that forwards requests to backend servers.  The backend servers use mod_access to allow or deny access to specific directories.  Before implementing a proxy server with backend web servers, the one web server used a syntax like:

order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 10.10.4
allow from domain.com

but now, the ip and domain are always the proxy server.  I know the X-Forwarded_For ip is set, but I don't know how to add that into the mod_access configuration.  And I don't see the forwarded host at all.  Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested but should work:

Backend config:

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^192\.168\.0\." allowme
order allow,deny
allow from env=allowme
deny from all
```

This would allow from 192.168.0.0/24 and block all others..

Comment: Is there any way to add pass the domain name of the requesting client and allow based on that?

Comment: The hostname for the requesting ip? Sorry, that is not part of the http-request and is almost impossible to know, the reverse record for the requesting ip, maybe but I'm not sure how to use it...

Comment: Found the answer on another site.  you have to make sure HostnameLookups is turned on on the load balancer and add the lines:

SetEnvIf Remote_Host "(.*)" remote=$1

RequestHeader set x-rem-host %{remote}e

to the configuration file.  then "x-rem-host" is available on the individual web servers.  thanks for your help!